# preserving hyperlink from cell when doing REGEXREPLACE in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, doing `=REGEXREPLACE(B10,".*\. ","")` correctly turns `"1. a" to "a"` but the hyperlink from B10 cell is gone, is there a way to preserve this link automatically, or any way to transfer the link to the new cell automatically?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: the output is just a cell, say C10, containing "a" hyperlinked to the same link as what was in B10. i guess better question to ask is just how to get the hyperlink from another cell

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used `Insert Hyperlink` menu to insert the hyperlink in B10, copied B10 to C10 (preserved the hyperlink), then replaced C10 with `=REGEXREPLACE(B10,".*\. ","")`, which removed the hyperlink.

You could try using `HYPERLINK` function to explicitly define hyperlinks, like this:

B10: `=HYPERLINK("https://google.com","1. a")`

C10: `=HYPERLINK("https://google.com",REGEXREPLACE(B10,".*\. ",""))`

Comment: Kindly let me know if this solved your issue or there are problems. Thank you.